# Unable to deserialize an encrypted array in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, encryption, serialization

The following code in my program serializes, encrypts and writes the byte array to disk.  From the looks of it, the encryption works fine.  The issue arises when the program decrypts and then deserializes the file.

Visual Studio displays the following error:
'System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException' occurred in System.Runtime.Serialization.dll

Additional information: There was an error deserializing the object of type Test.Store. The data at the root level is invalid.

I've been stuck on this one for two days, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

The following code has been trimmed down from its original form:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

namespace Test
{
    public class K
    {
        #region Non-Public Data Members

        private string _n = string.Empty;
        private string _u = string.Empty;
        private string _p = string.Empty;
        private string _u2 = null;
        private string _n2 = string.Empty;

        public K()
        {

        }
        public string T
        {
            get { return _n; }
            set { _n = value; }
        }

        public string U
        {
            get { return _u; }
            set { _u = value; }
        }

        public string P
        {
            get { return _p; }
            set { _p = value; }
        }

        public string U2
        {
            get { return _u2; }
            set { _u2 = value; }
        }

        public string N2
        {
            get { return _n2; }
            set { _n2 = value; }
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            //stuff
            return sb.ToString();
        }
        #endregion
    }
    public class Group
    {
        private string _text = string.Empty;
        private int _imageIndex = 0;

        private List<K> _credentials = new List<K>();

        public Group()
        {
        }

        public Group(string text, int imageIndex)
        {
            _text = text;
            _imageIndex = imageIndex;
        }

        public string Text
        {
            get { return _text; }
            set { _text = value; }
        }

        public int ImageIndex
        {
            get { return _imageIndex; }
            set { _imageIndex = value; }
        }

        public List<K> Ks
        {
            get { return _credentials; }
            set { _credentials = value; }
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Text;
        }

    }
    public class Store
    {
        private List<Group> _groups = new List<Group>();
        private string _docname = string.Empty;
        private bool _dirtyBit = false;

        public bool DirtyBit
        {
            get { return _dirtyBit; }
            set { _dirtyBit = value; }
        }

        public List<Group> Groups
        {
            get { return _groups; }
            set { _groups = value; }
        }

        public string DocName
        {
            get { return _docname; }
            set { _docname = value; }
        }

    }

    public class Crypto
    {
        public static string secretKey = "abcdefgh";
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("KERNEL32.DLL", EntryPoint = "RtlZeroMemory")]
        public static extern bool ZeroMemory(ref string Destination, int Length);
        static string GenerateKey()
        {
            DESCryptoServiceProvider desCrypto = (DESCryptoServiceProvider)DESCryptoServiceProvider.Create();
            return ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(desCrypto.Key);
        }

        public static byte[] PerformCrypto(ICryptoTransform cryptoTransform, byte[] data)
        {
            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, cryptoTransform, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    cryptoStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                    cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
                    return memoryStream.ToArray();
                }
            }
        }
        public static byte[] Decrypt(byte[] cipherTextBytes)
        {
            DESCryptoServiceProvider DES = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
            DES.Key = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(secretKey);
            DES.IV = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(secretKey);
            using (var decryptor = DES.CreateDecryptor(DES.Key, DES.IV))
            {
                return PerformCrypto(decryptor, cipherTextBytes);
            }
        }

        public static byte[] Encrypt(byte[] plainTextBytes)
        {
            DESCryptoServiceProvider DES = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
            DES.Key = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(secretKey);
            DES.IV = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(secretKey);
            using (var encryptor = DES.CreateEncryptor(DES.Key, DES.IV))
            {
                return PerformCrypto(encryptor, plainTextBytes);
            }
        }
    }

    public static class StoreMgr
    {
        private static Store _doc = new Store();

        public static void FileSaveAs(string fn)
        {
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Store));
                serializer.WriteObject(ms, _doc);
                byte[] byteArrayInput = ms.GetBuffer();
                byte[] encryptedBuffer = Crypto.Encrypt(byteArrayInput);
                File.WriteAllBytes(fn, encryptedBuffer);
            }
        }

        public static void OpenFile(string fn)
        {
                StoreMgr._doc = new Store();
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Crypto.Decrypt(File.ReadAllBytes(fn))))
            {
                    DataContractSerializer deserializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Store));
                    StoreMgr._doc = (Store)new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Store)).ReadObject(ms);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I've been stuck on this for quite some time. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Find out why the data at the root level is invalid.

Comment: In `OpenFile` Method why are you casting `ms` to `Stream`? its already of type `Stream`  .
`StoreMgr._doc = (Store)new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Store)).ReadObject((Stream)ms); // Stream cast is not required`

Comment: 1 more question, what is the use of `PerformCrypto` Method? What acutally it is doing?

Comment: @RobertHarvey That's the part I am trying to figure out.  I'm not completely familiar with C# and Visual Studio though.  Any thoughts?

Comment: @SandeepKushwah re: Stream Cast, thank you for catching that.  I have fixed that part. re: PerformCrypto Method.  All of the examples I saw for DESCryptoServiceProvider were using strings.  The one example I found using a byte array suggested setting it up that way.

Answer (score 0):

If you configure `System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener` in your web.config, you may find more helpful information in `*.svclog`

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in the FileSaveAs method.  byte[] byteArrayInput = ms.GetBuffer() was returning unused bytes.  After switching it to byte[] byteArrayInput = ms.ToArray() program ran fine.  Thanks for everyone's help.